# Why does limit still return the entire document set in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

This seems to be causing my queries to be slow, and I'm confused as to why it is returning all entries of the document.

```
>> Product.skip(0).limit(20).count
=> 3826
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the behaviour of the count(), which returns the count of the [records the query touched](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Count)

You need to use **size()** to count the current set.